# Cannot move / copy files between panes in Nemo after update

Tags: filemanager, gconf, nemo

I use multiplae panes a lot to move or copy files between panes. After Nautilus made the multiple panes disappear, I used the Webupd8's Repository so i can get that functionality back.
Then, after a recent update, the context menu option to move / copy files between panes disappeared too...

It seemed to me that no one was bothered by it - because i couldn't even find any mention of the problem, so i set out to find the solution by myself, and now that I found it - I decided to share it with the community. I am sure someone found that an annoyance, like i did.

Comment: Ask a question and write an answer as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, here we go:

First we have to install the DConf Editor

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Search for **dconf** in Unity and run it.

Navigate to  `org--> nemo --> preferences`.

Tick the `context-menus-show-all-actions` item.

Restart Nemo by either right-clicking its' Launcher icon and clicking **Quit**, or entering `killall nemo` in a terminal window.

It is also possible to do it in a terminal window with a one liner:

```
gsettings set org.nemo.preferences context-menus-show-all-actions true
```